# Is consuming GMOs safe

Tags: organic

We hear a lot of negative things about genetically modified organisms (GMO), are they harmful to humans when consumed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the health or nutritional aspects of crops. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information about the types of questions we allow.

Comment: this isn't the place for this discussion - as it stands, it's a very contentious issue, with arguments and evidence on both sides, and no definitive answers anyway, I'm afraid. In the UK, we just won't consume anything GM, and other than one or two strictly controlled areas, don't grow GM anything either. As a nation, we seem to stick to 'if in doubt, don't'!